# If $x$ is a global minimum, which of the following statements are true?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable

If $x$ is a global minimum, which of the following statements are true?

1. $v \to f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T v$ is tangent to $f$ at $x$
2. $\nabla f(x) = 0$
3. If $x' \neq x,$ then $\nabla f(x') \neq 0$

My thought:
#2 is obvious I think. But for #1, I don't understand what "$\nabla f(x)^T v$" represents.

Also for #3, what do I get for $x'$? Is this a derivative of a vector? Isn't it just $1$ then?

Comment: For #3, $x'$ just means “some point different from $x$”, the prime has nothing to do with derivatives here.

Comment: @HansLundmark ah!  Thanks! Shoot.. haha

Comment: $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector, so $\triangledown f(x)^T v$ is an inner product.